# Send path, not file to local server

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

I have local (only) daemon that's file parser. UI will be written in React.js I want to avoid Electron (has full file system paths for file input fields).

File path should be send via websocket to daemon for processing. I know about browser security and fact file system paths are hidden. Uploading whole file locally is just stupid. Is there any way to pass-through that problem or should I rethink my idea?

Comment: If I understand your question, you're wanting to get an absolute path to a file uploaded to a locally hosted site. AFAIK this is not possible from the browser

Comment: @ioseph Yes, exactly. I expected answer like that :/ Must change my approach to problem.